# Erro de sintaxe em Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou testando um trecho de código aqui em javascript e está dando erro de sintaxe na linha 12. Diz que está faltando um `;` em algum lugar, mas eu já revirei esse código e não to conseguindo encontrar o erro.

Este código originalmente foi escrito em C e estou tentando adaptar para um problema específico usando javascript. Alterei valores definidos como inteiros para `var`, já alterei para tipo `char` já que javascript é fracamente tipado e o `==` meio que "contorna" as diferenças de tipo das variáveis.

```js
    var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    var r = "3";
    var n = (arr.length)/(arr[0].length);
    var data[r];

    function combinationUtil(var arr[], var data[], var start, var end, var index, var r)
    {
      // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
      if (index == r)
      {
        for (var j=0; j<r; j++){
          console.log(data[j]);
          //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[j];

        }

      }

      // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
      // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
      // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
      // at remaining positions
      for (var i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
      {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);

      }
    }

    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
```

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Qual seria essa linha 12?

Comment: Perdão pela demora em responder. É a linha que indicaram abaixo que contém var data[r];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

além do erro de sintaxe apontado pelo @YurePereira, ainda temos o Erro da linha 12:

```
var data[r];
```

Você está declarando este array da forma errada, neste caso você tem duas opções:

Sem informar o tamanho do array, deixe que o JavaScript defina isto em runtime.

```
var data = [];
```

Crie um objeto Array com tamanho r.

```
var data = new Array(r);
```

Segue abaixo o seu script funcionando.:

```js
var data = [];
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var r = 3;
var n = arr.length;

var demo = document.getElementById("demo");

function combinationUtil(arr, data, start, end, index, r)
{
  // Current combination is ready to be printed, print it
  if (index == r)
  {
    var demo = document.createElement("div");
    demo.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.slice(0, r));
    document.body.appendChild(demo);
  }

  // replace index with all possible elements. The condition
  // "end-i+1 >= r-index" makes sure that including one element
  // at index will make a combination with remaining elements
  // at remaining positions
  for (var i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
  {
    data[index] = arr[i];
    combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
  }
}

combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta mais completa com o código rodando.

Answer (score 4):

Remove os `var` e os [] dos parâmetros da função `combinationUtil`, pois da forma que está isso faz dar erro de sintaxe.

```
function combinationUtil(arr, data, start, end, index, r)
{

    if (index == r)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            console.log(data[j]);
        }

    }

    for (var i = start; i <= end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
    {
        data[index] = arr[i];
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.